# "Fahren in" vs. "Fahren zu"

Tags: word-usage, preposition

In einem didaktischen Buch bin ich auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen:

> Frau Müller hat eine neue Wohnung. Sie braucht auch neue Möbel. Sie fährt mit einer Freundin **in** ein Möbelgeschäft und kauft ein.

Ist das richtig und gängig? Da Deutsch nicht meine Muttersprache ist, habe ich Schwierigkeiten, diesen Satz so zu begreifen. Wäre es nicht besser gewesen, *"zu einem Möbelgeschäft fahren"* zu sagen? Wenn man *"in ein Geschäft fährt"*, werden wohl nicht die anderen eher verstehen, dass Frau Müller und ihre Freundin mit dem Auto eben *"ins Geschäft"* fahren und dabei vielleicht Kunden überrollen?

Comment: _" werden wohl nicht die anderen eher verstehen, dass Frau Müller und ihre Freundin mit dem Auto eben "ins Geschäft" fahren und dabei vielleicht Kunden überrollen?"_ Das hängt im Wesentlichen vom Kontext ab. Mit der ganzen Vorgeschichte _"Frau Müller hat eine neue Wohnung. bla blah ..."_ ist es hinreichend klar, dass Frau Müller nicht mit ihrem Auto ins Möbelgeschäft gekracht ist. _in_ und _zu_ sind in vielerlei Hinsicht bei lokalen Kontexten mehr oder weniger austauschbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, du hast recht, hier wäre e besser gewesen zu schreiben

> Frau Müller fährt **zu** einem Möbelgeschäft.

Durch diese Formulierung wird klar, dass das Ziel von Frau Müllers Reise das Möbelgeschäft ist, es wird aber auch klar dass die Fahrt in unmittelbarer Nähe des Geschäfts endet. Wenn im selben Kontext dann vom Möbelkauf die Rede ist, ist auch klar, dass die Möbel in jenem Geschäft gekauft werden, in dessen unmittelbarer Nähe sich der Endpunkt der Fahrt befindet.

Das gilt aber nur für *»fahren«*. (Eigentlich für alle Bewegungsverben, die die Benutzung eines Fahrzeuges implizieren, aber außer *»fahren«* fallen mir gerade keine anderen ein.)

Das gilt nicht unbedingt auch für *»gehen«:*

> Frau Müller **geht zu** einem Möbelgeschäft.

Das bedeutet erstmal nur, dass sie dorthin geht. Aus diesem Satz allein kann noch nicht geschlossen werden, dass sie auch hinein geht. Erst wenn vom Einkaufen die Rede ist, ergibt sich auch diese Bedeutung. Klarer ist diese Formulierung:

> Frau Müller **geht in** ein Möbelgeschäft.

Jetzt ist ganz eindeutig klar, dass das Ziel ihrer Reise das Innere des Möbelgeschäftes ist. Die Absicht, dort etwas zu kaufen, steckt nicht direkt in diesem Satz, weil das aber bei den sehr vielen Möbelhausbesuchern der Fall ist, kann man mit einer gewissen Wahrscheinlichkeit auch eine Kaufabsicht unterstellen.

---

Ergänzung:

Zu beachten ist auch, dass es in bestimmten Konstellationen auch regionale Bedeutungsunterschiede gibt:

> 1. Paul geht zur Schule.
> 2. Paul geht in die Schule.

Variante 1 ist meiner Beobachtung nach in ganz Deutschland gängig, Variante 2 wird hingegen vor allem in Österreich verwendet. In Österreich wird Variante 1 so verstanden:

> Paul geht zur Schule und bleibt davor stehen. Er geht nicht hinein.

Siehe auch: [Alfred Dorfer: Deutsche und Österreicher - Früher und Heute | Spätschicht (Youtube](https://youtu.be/oljV4De4Q4k?t=57))

Dieser Bedeutungsunterschied beruht aber weniger auf einer unterschiedlichen Interpretation der Präpositionen, sondern vielmehr darauf, was man unter dem Begriff »Schule« versteht. In Deutschland meint man die Institution, in Österreich das Gebäude.

Comment: Der letzte Absatz ist überflüssig. Offensichtlich gibtbes doch einen engeren Zusammenhang, den die von dir dargelegt, übliche Erklärung nicht zu verschleiern vermag, ist "ein Laden" doch genauso grob umrissenes Konstrukt.

Answer (score 3):

Sie haben recht. Zwischen den Ausdrücken

> 1. **zu** einem Möbelgeschäft fahren
> 2. **in** ein Möbelgeschäft fahren

besteht eigentlich ein inhaltlicher Unterschied. Und sofern Ausdruck 1. gemeint ist, empfinde ich (im norddeutschen Sprachraum aufgewachsen) es zumindest als unüblich, Ausdruck 2. zu verwenden. Die Funktion von Präpositionen besteht ja gerade darin, inhaltliche Unterschied darstellen zu können.

Zu beachten ist, dass es beim Gebrauch von Präpositionen regionale Besonderheiten geben kann. Als Beispiel habe ich eine Grafik aus dem [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f10c-e/) für das Verb *gehen* angefügt.
(Es hat, wie Mitglied @HubertSchölnast richtig bemerkt hat, mit der eigentlichen Frage wenig zu tun, soll aber den Aspekt, dass es solche Besonderheiten gibt, verdeutlichen.)

[image: Ich gehe … Aldi/Lidl.]

Allerdings gehe ich bei dem vorliegenden Textauszug nicht von einer regionalen Besonderheit aus, denn wenn ich Sie richtig verstanden habe, stammt er aus einem Lehrbuch, und er weist ja auch sonst keine Auffälligkeiten auf.

Comment: Trotzdem ist es gängig die Ausdrücke austauschbar zu verwenden. Soweit ich weiß gibt's da auch keine regionalen Besonderheiten. _Ich fahre in den Supermarkt, Einkaufen._ wird genauso verwendet (und richtig verstanden) wie _Ich fahre zum Supermarkt, Einkaufen._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Nie würde ich *Ich **fahre in** den Supermarkt sagen* (es sei denn, ich täte genau das), sondern *Ich **gehe in** den Supermarkt* oder *Ich **fahre zum** Supermarkt*. Da Sie es trotzdem gängig finden, scheint es wohl doch regionale Unterschiede zu geben.

Comment: Ich lebe in Süddeutschland, Oberbayern um genau zu sein.

Comment: Ich im Nordosten. ;-)

Comment: Ich dachte mir's fast :). Ja es scheint offensichtlich regionale Unterschiede zu geben. Bei uns ist das im Sprachgebrauch wirklich austauschbar, und hängt eher vom Kontext der Verwendung ab, und ich würde mich auch nicht daran stören, wenn ich es so in der Zeitung oder einem Buch lese.

Comment: Die Ergebnisse, die in der Karte dargestellt sind, haben aber mit der Frage nichts zu tun. In der Frage ging es um *»in ein Geschäft fahren«,* also um die Verwendung eines Fahrzeuges. Die Karte bezieht sich auf *»Einkaufen gehen«.* Das ist nicht, wonach gefragt wurde.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, bitte nicht böse sein! Aber ich wundere mich schon, dass ausgerechnet Sie das schreiben, der fast alle seine Antworten gern mit Nebensächlichem aufbläht. ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Es geht doch hier darum, dass ein Nicht-Muttersprachler Schwierigkeiten hat, zu verstehen, wie das richtig sein kann. Das zeugt von einem schon ziemlich guten Verständnis. Und wenn wir es genau nehmen, ist *in* hier einfach falsch verwendet. Muttersprachler können das als künstlerische Freiheit betrachten. Aber jemand, der versucht, die Anwendung von Präpositionen sinnvoll zu verallgemeinern, muss doch hier ins Grübeln kommen, oder?

Comment: @Olafant Ich habe ja auch nur festgestellt, was ich wahrnehme. Ich grüble mittlerweile ja selbst darüber. Ich muss mal bei Facebook Freunden und Kollegen aus Norddeutschland fragen, ob _"Ich fahr' jetzt in den Supermarkt, Einkaufen."_ irgendwie merkwürdig für sie klingt.

Comment: @Björn Ich bin mir nicht so sicher, ob _gehen_ oder _fahren_ nicht möglicherweise doch einen Unterschied macht. Es würde zum Beispiel niemand auf die Idee kommen zu sagen _"Ich fahre in's Volksfest."_ es sei denn, er hätte einen Anschlag geplant. _"Ich fahre auf's Volksfest."_ und _"Ich fahre zum Volksfest."_ sind analog zu _gehen_ aber wieder austauschbar (IMO).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Verstehe ich vollkommen. Wenn man das ohne groß zu überlegen, wie es Muttersprachler in der Regel tun, ständig verwendet und hört, findet man das nicht ungewöhnlich. Das ist ja das gute hier: dass wir von Nicht-Muttersprachlern (sozusagen von außen betrachtet) etwas über unsere intuitiv gelernte Sprache lernen können. ;)

Comment: *In die Erdbeeren fahren*, *in die Pilze*, (etc.?) ist durchaus idiomatisch (auf's Feld, zum selbst sammeln)

Answer (score -1):

Die fahren nicht hin, gucken lediglich durchs Schaufenster, fahren wieder heim und bestellen dann beim nächsten Online-Händler. Die gehen da auch in das Geschäft hinein!

So oder so ist der Ausdruck unterspezifiziert, dabei aber hinreichend genau. Ggf. hat das Geschäft sogar ein Parkhaus, oder weite Grenzen, dann *fahren* die da wirklich mit der Karre hinein!

Das ist eine noch relativ übliche Ausdrucksweise, denke ich, die darauf fußen mag, dass Fahren und Gehen hinreichend austauschbar sind. Wenn ich gen Italien fahre, beinhaltet das auch den ganzen Urlaub inklusive der Strecken, die zu Fuß zurückgelegt werden.

Eine wortwörtliche Übersetzung etwa in Englisch kann den Ausdruck natürlich verbalhornen, so wie auch umgekehrt, denn wir treiben sozusagen auch nicht in den Schuppen bei der Karre und wir gehen auch nicht bei dem Bus ein zu die höhere Märktchen.

Darüber ist letztendlich auch nicht klar ob *into* überhaupt der angemessene Vergleichswert ist. So unüberschaubar wie die Auswüchse der Urindogermanischen Lokativa waren (*h1en- "in", *h2en- "on", *h2ent- "anti, an", s. *Antlitz*" Gesicht", *h2enteros "unter, hinter", etc.) sowie die Dialektlandschaft auch in deutschen Landen höchst vielfältig gewesen, könnte es sich bei unserem "in" auch (also nicht exklusiv) um eine ländliche Form von "gen" handeln (siehe oben, Nieder Deutsch wohl regulär *i'en, vgl. *gegen* "again(st)" wie "anti") oder eine Abart von *an*. Vergleich aber auch *einfahren*, *einkaufen*, deutlich auf *Einnahmen* bezogen (in-come, yield), im Gegensatz zu Annahme (acquisition, acception, assumption). Vorallem will ich aber behaupten sei die Grundform *in's* ununterscheidbar von **inz*, welches regulär Englisch *int(o)* entsprechen dürfte, sodass "zu" immerhin erkennbar bliebe, während die Maßgabe, eine kontrahierte Artikelei liege zu Grunde, als ob "in das, in ein" (so auch *in'n*) leider die vorherschende Meinung darstellt, die immerhin nicht gänzlich falsch ist. Das ist halt das vorherrschende Sprachnazitum, das pflegt alles andersartige gleich als abartig und grundsätzlich falsch zu bezeichnen ohne sich auch mal an die eigene Nase zu fassen.

Die Kritik stimmt wohl, da der Ausdruck unpräzise ist, ist dies auch potentiel missverständlich und daher wie in einer anderen Antiwort angedeutet wurde eindeutig regional begrenzt.